# Pain Brings Joy

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle

When I search for pain, it brings such joy

What is it that I seek?

Hint:

> While Macs bring me displeasure, I cannot find what I'm looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess:

> The puzzle is about [MS Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint).

Because:

> On a default Windows installation, MS Paint is the first result when typing "pain" into the search bar. A fairly well known PBS art series is "The Joy of Painting," with Bob Ross. So, when searching for "pain" you instead find joy, through painting.
> This doesn't work on an Apple/Mac computer, because they don't have the same default programs.